# How to compare the column names in one table to the values in another in impala

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

first is the main table and second is the lookup table.
I need to compare the column names of first table to the values in the second table and if a certain column name is found in any row of the second table then fetch some fields out of second table.

Is it possible to do it in impala?

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfMpV.png)

```
source    |location  |origin   
----------+----------+-------
s1        |india     |xxx
```

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKI7P.png)

```
extractedfrom|lct       |lkp_value|map_value    
-------------+----------+---------+---------
s1           |location  |india    |india_x
s1           |origin    |xxx      |yyyyyy
```

i need to have something like
[final view required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKudD.png)

```
source    |location  |origin    |location_ll|origin_lkp
----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------
s1        |india     |xxx       |india_x    |yyyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your post to be more specific about what you are trying to do and how you wish to join the tables.

The following query should work for you given the example you provided.

```
SELECT t1.source,
       t1.location,
       t1.origin,
       t2_loc.map_value AS location_lkp,
       t2_ori.map_value AS origin_lkp
  FROM Table1 t1
  JOIN Table2 t2_loc ON t1.source = t2_loc.extractedfrom
                    AND t1.location = t2_loc.lkp_value
  JOIN Table2 t2_ori ON t1.source = t2_ori.extractedfrom 
                    AND t1.origin = t2_ori.lkp_value
 WHERE t2_loc.lct = 'location'
   AND t2_ori.lct = 'origin'
```

The trick is that you join to `Table2` multiple times - one for each column you wish to match upon.